"en moins confortable"?
Saw this line in a book:

“La voiture ressemblait à une caisse à savon, en moins
confortable.”

I understand it means "The car looked like a soapbox, only less comfortable," but I've never seen en used this way, I don't think. I'm trying to understand the grammar here. I would've expected "mais moins confortable" or something else. I just don't quite grasp how en functions here.

Here, the idiom en moins1 is used:

TLFi Moins
I. − Adverbe de quantité
A. − Comparatif d'infériorité
[..]
2. Dans des locutions.
[..]
b) Locution adverbiale
[..]
♦ En moins + adjectif. Avec une intensité, une qualité moindre. J'ai beaucoup d'elle, mais en moins bon et en moins rude (George Sand, Histoire de ma vie, t. 2, 1855, p. 247). Voilà bien mes enthousiasmes, en moins long (Jules Renard, Journal, 1900, p.612).

En is used the same way 'only' is indeed used in your English translation.
We might translate:

The future is much like the present, only longer (Dan Quisenberry)

to

Le futur, c'est un peu comme le présent mais en plus long.

Similar sentences with the preposition en:

Je voudrais ces chaussures en 42.  (I would like these shoes in size 9.5)


J'ai les mêmes en bleu. (I have the same ones in blue.)

1 Other similar locutions adverbiales: En moins + adjective, en mieux, en pire.

So is en the same part of speech here as in "en cuir" or "en France", as oppposed to its pronoun usage like "j'en souviens"? I realize that's confusing, but I mean when  en is used in this expression "en moins [adj]", I would read it not as a pronoun but as .... whatever part of speech it is when saying "J'habite en France"?

Or do I actually have it backwards, and it IS a pronoun here, and I should think of "en moins confortable" as "[but compared to it] less comfortable"

Not a pronoun, it's a preposition like Je vais voir le même film, mais en VO sous-titrée. "I'm going to see the same movie but its subtitled original version*.

After reading your question and your comments, I can provide some explanations, but they don't come easy.
I
"En" in "en moins confortable" has nothing to do with "en" in "en cuir" or "en France".
In "en cuir" the word "en" introduces a "complément de matière" (it is used to tell what is the type of material constituting a particular thing).

(TLFi)
5. [En introduit un compl. circ. de matière]

J'ai les intérieurs en duvet de canard (Aymé, Cléramb.,1950, p. 168)
En fonte, en terre, en grès, en porcelaine, en aluminium, en étain, que de marmites, de poêles, de pot-au-feu, de fait-tout, de cassolettes, de soupières, de plats, de timbales, de passoires, de hachoirs, de moulins, de moules, de mortiers! Beauvoir, Mém. j. fille,1958p. 77.


In "en France" the word "en" introduces a "complément de lieu (lieu où on est ou lieu où on va)". It is used to say where someone or something is or is going; the type of place can be  figurative, though, and it is not easy to determine that place is what is involved in that case (you might consult the TLFi, II. − [Analyse sém.] A. − [En introduit un compl. circ.]
1. [Un compl. circ. de lieu]). However, "en" in "en moins confortable" has nothing to do with any part of that entry.
It is not a pronoun, as in "je m' en souviens" ("j'en souviens" is incorrect, in all cases); it stands for nothing; it is true that the pronoun "en", sometimes, does not have an antecedent, and the expression in which it occurs is then a fixed expression; however, even when this is so, it is used in conjunction with a verb, and this is not the case in this expression; since "en" can only be a pronoun or a preposition it must be a preposition. The idea of comparison is correct, even if the pronoun "it" is not represented by "en". This question is difficult insofar as the semantic analysis of the TLFi is not consistent. I'll try to explain this in some detail.
"En moins + adj." is  categorized as a fixed expression ("loc. adv.") in the TLFi, but its opposite, "en plus + adj.", is not, and there is, therefore, an inconsistency. This can be seen clearly from the entries, which show a striking symmetry, as one might expect; "en plus" is in "1.", whereas "en moins" is in "2.", as a fixed expression. The example  for "en plus" shows that clearly (see entry for "en plus + adj." below)  ; this example,

"Quand j'en approchai, je reconnus qu'elles [des montagnes] ne présentaient, en plus grand, que le même aspect stérile et dépouillé des montagnes de la Judée",

rewritten as follows,

"Quand j'en approchai, je reconnus qu'elles [des montagnes] ne présentaient que le même aspect stérile et dépouillé des montagnes de la Judée, en plus grand."

matches the form of “La voiture ressemblait à une caisse à savon, en moins confortable." and of "Voilà bien mes enthousiasmes, en moins long.".
The term "aspect" represents what is bigger ("plus grand" ("que l'aspect des montagnes de Judée")),  the term "voiture" represents what is less comfortable ("moins confortable" ("qu'une caisse à savon"); you can say as well, along with the definition for "en plus" the following.

Avec telle qualité (le confort), à un degré inférieur, par comparaison (à une caisse à savon)


(TLFi) moins
I. − Adv. de quantité
A. − Compar. d'infériorité
1. [Dans un système compar., exprime une qualité ou une intensité inférieure, soit à cette même qualité ou intensité chez un autre être ou objet, soit à une autre qualité ou intensité]
a) [Le morphème compar., corrélatif de moins (mais qui peut être sous-entendu) est la conj. que] Moins... (que)
[…]
2. Dans des loc.
c) Loc. prép.
♦ En moins + adj. Avec une intensité, une qualité moindre.

J'ai beaucoup d'elle, mais en moins bon et en moins rude (Sand, Hist. vie, t. 2, 1855, p.247).
Voilà bien mes enthousiasmes, en moins long (Renard, Journal, 1900, p.612).



(TLFi)  plus
I. − Adv. de quantité
A. − Compar. de supériorité
1. [Dans un système compar., exprime une qualité ou une intensité supérieure, soit à cette même qualité ou intensité chez un autre être ou objet, soit à une autre qualité ou intensité]
a) [Le morph. compar., corrél. de plus (mais qui peut être sous-entendu) est la conj. que] Plus... (que).
γ) [La compar. consiste à situer ce dont on parle sur une échelle et à le déclarer supérieur à une qualité signifiée par un adj. ou un subst. ou nom. à valeur d'adj. introd. par que] C'est plus que beau, c'est superbe. Un petit clerc de notaire vivant avec sa mère, tous deux plus que pauvres (Barrès, Cahiers, t.10, 1913, p.15).D'ici là, ma position peut devenir plus que brillante. Le tout est de commencer, de se mettre à pied d'oeuvre (Duhamel, Terre promise, 1934, p.13).
− En plus + adj. Avec telle qualité, à un degré supérieur, par comparaison.

Quand j'en approchai, je reconnus qu'elles [des montagnes] ne présentaient, en plus grand, que le même aspect stérile et dépouillé des montagnes de la Judée (Lamart., Voy. Orient, t.2, 1835, p.9).


The fact that "avec" is a preposition typically used for "compléments de manière"  could induce the thinking that this expression is akin to a "copmplément de manière";  introducing such complepents is one of the functions of "en" (see below the TLFi's section on "en" as such a word); however, it appears that this not so: "avec" has other meanings.

Il y arrivait avec difficulté.  (manner)
Les gens gravissaient la pente avec lenteur.  (manner)


(TLFi)
B. − [En introduit un compl. circ. de manière]
3. [Le compl. évoque une forme, un aspect]
De la ferraille en tas (Cendrars, Bourlinguer,1948p. 305). Du chocolat en poudre (Druon, Gdes fam.,t. 1, 1948, p. 98). Il neige sur les mots en ski (Aragon, Rom. inach.,1956, p. 215).Nous sortions en bande (Beauvoir, Mém. j. fille,1958, p. 297)

L'auto, un fort cabriolet huit cylindres, couleur havane, laminait sous ses larges pneus les flaques de boue, en jaillissements sales. Van der Meersch, L'Empreinte du dieu,1936, p. 7.
Pendant qu'Elena, armée du cure-dent, les [les escargots] chatouillait consciencieusement sous le ventre, je tendais des ficelles en l'air, d'une branchette à l'autre, en ligne droite, en diagonale, en zigzag, en rond, en étoile, ... Cendrars, Bourlinguer,1948p. 217.
La fable s'empara de lui; les colporteurs vendaient son portrait. On le vit en tabatière, en presse-papier. On le peignit au fond des plats et des assiettes. Guéhenno, Jean-Jacques, Grandeur et misère d'un esprit, 1952, p. 339.


II Conclusion
It seems evident that, as for "en plus + adj.", "en moins + adj." fits into the definition of a system of comparison. In the words of the TLFi this amounts to the following.

On trouve « en moins + adj. »  « Dans un système compar., [et cette expression] exprime une qualité ou une intensité inférieure à cette même qualité ou intensité chez un autre être ou objet ».

One more example

Le filme muet, techniquement, n'est pas autre chose que le cinéma moderne, en moins fidèle dans la représentation du mouvement, et le son en moins.

« En » could be thought to express manner, and the expression would be a "complément de manière", but that does not seem  correct, which is another reason that points to  the "locution adverbiale" classification being improper. "En moins confortable" is an expression that describes a COI ("ressembler à" is "transitif direct"). I don't think that it is possible to say that the manner the car looked like a soapbox was "only less confortable" ("en moins confortable"). "Moins de confort" was just not part of the resemblance. Instead, it appears more exact to view this type of expression as a type of elliptical phrase in apposition.

La voiture ressemblait à une caisse à savon, en moins confortable.
La voiture ressemblait à une caisse à savon, une caisse à savon dont le confort habituel est absent. (The equivalent formulation highlights the existence of an apposition to "une caisse à savon", ("une caisse à savon dont le confort habituel d'un tel véhicule est absent").)

